# Infinitely many dissociated sets of any size, only even integer elements?

Tags: number-theory

For any positive integer N, can we have infinitely many dissociated sets (no subset sums to the same number) of size N comprising only even positive integers?

I guess it's true because by induction if we start with a dissociated set of size N-1, we can compute all sums of subsets, then pick the next even integer after the greatest sum, and add that to the set to yield a dissociated set of size N. And we have infinitely many because we can translate any dissociated set by any even number.

Comment: What role does $N$ play in your request?

Comment: @Stefan thanks, I didn't notice that; edited

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already gave a proof outline, so all we can do is make the proof more formal.

So we first show the existence of a dissociated set of size $N$ consisting of even integer elements, which can be explicitly constructed.
Fix $N \ge 1$ and consider the set $\{2^i \mid  1 \le i \le N \}$ of size $N$.
Then for a subset $I \subset \{1 , \dots N \}$ we can write $\sum_{i \in I} 2^i$ in base $2$, from which we can reconstruct $I$ by the places of the $1$'s. So if $\sum_{j \in J} 2^j = \sum_{i \in I }2^i$ for $I,J \subset \{1 , \dots , N\}$ we must have $I=J$. (Note that those sets are exactly your sets, just explicitly written out).

However, if we consider the translated set $\{4,6,10 \}$ of $\{2,4,8\}$, we see that $\{ 4,6,10\}$ is not dissociated as $4+6=10$, so we must find another way to create infinitely many dissociated sets of size $N$.

So we can consider the sets $\{ \{ k^i \mid 1 \le i \le N \} \mid k \textrm{ even positive integer}\}$. Then you can easily show that $\{ k^i \mid 1 \le i \le N \} \neq \{ l^i \mid 1 \le i \le N \}$ if $ l \neq k$ by comparing the smallest elements of both sets.
Furthermore, by writing the sums of a subset of $\{ k^i \mid 1 \le i \le N \}$ in base $k$ we can recover the subset, so $\{ k^i \mid 1 \le i \le N \}$ is dissociated for all even integers $k$.
As there are infinitely many even positive integers $k$, the results follows.